# Change the text from pale blue to black in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I want to change the color of text in Google Chrome from pale blue (which is very hard to read) to black. How can I do this?

Comment: [so] duplicate: [how to auto change background color and text color of browsing websites in Chrome browser for custom visibility?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22443995)